# mysql - right joining two tables as one to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, join

I know that this question already asked many times here but after all I could't found my answer that what I want.

**My Question is:**

I have two tables and the structure of these tables is as:

**table1:**
`item_id, store,title,available,shipping`

**table2:**
`item_id, review_rate,user_id,review_title`

These tables should be join as `one to many` relation.

For example if the data in these tables is as:

```
table1:

item_id      store      title    available    shipping
-------------------------------------------------------
11           glasses    ..........................
12           dresses    ..........................
.
.
.

table2:

item_id     review_rate    user_id    review_title
--------------------------------------------------
11           3              10023      good item
11           5              10024      nice item
12           1              10024      nice one
.
.
.
```

then the result should be as after joining:

```
afterJoin:

item_id   store   title   available   shipping   rate   people_reviewed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
11        ....................................   4      2
12        ....................................   1      1
```

The `query` I tried to join is as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW afterJoin AS 
SELECT i.*,round(AVG(r.review_rate)) as rate,count(r.user_id) as people_reviewed 
   FROM table1 i 
   RIGHT JOIN  table2 r ON i.item_id = r.item_id
```

but this return only one row.

Comment: mysql is not equals SQL-server

Comment: thank you to improve my mistake

Comment: Why are you using a right join here? Why not a left join? When you use a right join you are going to get all reviews even if the row in table1 doesn't exist. It is possibly ok but most people think the other direction. You want all items and their reviews (if they exist). The way you have this coded you will not get an item returned if it doesn't have a review.

Comment: @SeanLange then what should i do?

Comment: I would probably use a left join...like I said in my previous comment. That way you get every row from table1 and the details from table2 when a review exists.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you. this was the another question that i was going to ask it on next time. you solved it once.

Comment: Might be worth your time to review the join types. https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause.  Without it your database is aggregating all of the records together.

```
SELECT i.*, round(AVG(r.review_rate)) as rate, count(r.user_id) as people_reviewed 
FROM table1 i 
    RIGHT JOIN  table2 r ON i.item_id = r.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id
```

The `GROUP BY` instructs the db to aggregate for each `item_id`.

Comment: thank you this one solved my question. This is your owe on me that you give your important time for the solution of my question

Comment: Glad I could help!